# replacement drive cage for power edge R710

Tags: configuration, dell-poweredge, io

Hi I'm performance tuning a DB server its a Dell R710 there is a very significant I/O bottleneck.  Unfortunately the server was purchased with the 6 x 3.5 inch sata configuration which doesn't give me the leeway I need to address the issue.  Before going to DAS does anyone know if it is possible to purchase a replacement front drive enclosure ?  I know the server is configurable with something like 12 or 16 2.5 inch drives and it appears to be modular ?  I tired contacting dell but the offshore parts department reps are not very bright lol.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you not have an account rep for Dell? That should be doable, however you'll need to change the backplane too.

Comment: It should be doable. But you may be better off finding the right server chassis from a Dell parts dealer or obtaining the right server setup. Also, you'll probably need a different controller setup to accommodate both drive cages.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES Unfortunately I'm an HP guy lol ... Do you have a number that I could get one ?

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna it's my understanding that Dell assigns their account reps based on geographical location so my rep would be different than yours. You'll likely want to look into getting a Dell Premier account - http://www.dell.com/content/topics/topic.aspx/global/premier/login/signin?c=us&~ck=pn

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna Just call the number on support.dell.com. Tell them what you need and ask for your regional sales rep to contact you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is latency building up and not more space I would go for iodrive. They are however quite expensive.